# Powershell passing arguments in ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, scriptblock

I'm trying to get the last write time on a file from a remote server.

This doesn not work:

```
$server = "MyServerName"

$lastWrite = Invoke-Command -Computername $server -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem "\\$args[0]\hot.war" } -argumentlist $server | select -Property LastWriteTime
```

This does work:

```
 $lastWrite = Invoke-Command -Computername $server -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem "\\MyServerName\hot.war" } -argumentlist $server | select -Property LastWriteTime
```

Can anyone help make the first set work?

Comment: Why are you using `"\\args[0]\ ` instead of putting `"\\$server\" ` ?

Comment: @luke - I tried that first and it didn't work.  Found this post to use args.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023012/passing-powershell-variables-into-a-scriptblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, if you are using PowerShell 3. You can do something like this:

```psh
$lastWrite = Invoke-Command -Computername $server -ScriptBlock {
               Get-ChildItem "\\$using:server\hot.war"
             } | select -Property LastWriteTime
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with variables in strings: `"\\$args[0]\hot.war"` will be expanded to `\\MyServerName[0]\hot.war`.

Use `"\\$($args[0])\hot.war"` to be sure that `$args[0]` will be treated as a single expression.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the server variable into your first line...

```
$server = "MyServerName"

$lastWrite = Invoke-Command -Computername $server -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem "\\$server\hot.war" } -argumentlist $server | select -Property LastWriteTime
```

Comment: That's where I had begun but it doesn't work.                                         Cannot find path '\\\\hot.war' because it does not exist.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023012/passing-powershell-variables-into-a-scriptblock